# QGIS 3.16.6 cannot load JPG

Tags: qgis, linux, jpg

I'm trying to load raster file JPG format into QGIS on Linux. And then I got this message:

```
Invalid Data Source : /home/name/map/13-36.jpg is not a valid or recognized data source.
```

If I use "Add Raster Layer", then it say:

```
Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset /home/name/map/113.jpg: libjpeg: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80 Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: /home/name/map/113.jpg
```

Same problem on QGIS 3.18. But on QGIS 3.10.4, It's complete normal.
Can anybody help me?

System info:
i7 4720 HQ
Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
Linux mint 20.1
Cinnamon 4.8.6

Comment: Did you try gdalinfo? Is the driver  JPEG/JPEG JFIF? Sometimes the file extension and the content doesn't match. A JPG image have to start with three magic codes FF D8 FF. Check it with od command. Some programs use extension to select driver, others use magic codes...

Comment: My assumption was false, QGIS 3.18 loads raster correct even if the extension is false. I get the same error message if I try to load the raster as a vector data set. Isn't it your case?

Comment: If I use "Add Raster Layer", then it say:
`Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset /home/name/map/113.jpg: libjpeg: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80 Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: /home/name/map/113.jpg`

Comment: please [edit] your question to add that useful information